# Are there fractal "manifolds"?

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, fractal-analysis

Differentiable manifolds are a generalization of the local geometry of Euclidean space. In fact, every differentiable manifold of dimension $m$ is locally diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space of the same dimension.

On the other hand, in general, curves and surfaces (and other fractal objects of higher dimension) that can be embedded in a Euclidean space in general, do not admit a simple differentiable structure, so they cannot be treated as differentiable manifolds.

I wonder if anyone has defined a kind of "fractal variety/manifold" that considers fractal geometries that are not explicitly constructions within a Euclidean space and in some sense can be analyzed intrinsically as are differentiable manifolds.

Comment: If I am remembering correctly it is a standard theorem that any differentiable manifold can be embedded isometrically in a sufficiently high dimensional euclidean space, and I believe the same is true for non differentiable manifolds. This means that any differentiable manifold can be viewed as a construction in euclidean space. If that isn't what you mean then the most obvious natural spaces to look at for studying fractals are general metric spaces where we use hausdorff dimension as a sort of measure of how fractal a space is.

Comment: @Fishbane for the differentiable case, we have for example the Whitney embedding theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem

Comment: Yes that is correct. Honestly this isn't necessarily my area of expertise so I don't know if I can give you much help beyond looking at genreal metric spaces. Apologies for that.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is, broadly speaking, "yes", but I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for.  There are numerous embedding results (Mañé gives a result for sets $X$ where the Hausdorff dimension of $X-X$ is finite; Assouad gives a similar result for finite Assouad dimension of $X-X$), but I am not sure that these are the kinds of things you are looking for.  If this is relevant, I can put it into an answer (though Robinson's book *Dimensions, Embeddings, and Attractors* might be a good place to start if I can't provide you with an answer).